# Workflow calling external executable

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation

In windows workflow foundation, can a workflow call another executable to be launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it is just code that runs so anything you can do in regular .NET code you can do from a workflow.